# Call to undefined function curl_init() in wampp

Tags: php, curl

I am getting an error. I have done the following:

1. Find file php.ini and uncomment in wamp apache folder
2. Find file php.ini and uncomment in wamp php folder
3. checked in wamp extensions
4. download file and replace php_curl-5.3.13-nts-VC9-x64.zip
5. restart wamp.

But I still get error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\test\curl_http_client.php on line 66
```

Comment: have you checked the `extension_dir` in php.ini? it shoule be something like `C:/pathtophp/ext' note: windows also use the forward slash for folder separator.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about guessing a software dependency or setup issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Call to undefined function curl_init

You either edit wrong `php.ini` file or something is missing on your system, preventing curl extension from loading. You shall check with `phpinfo()` where is proper `php.ini`, then check if you got `extension` entry for cURL really enabled. If so and it is still not working then next step should be checking Apache's `error.log` looking for detailed error messages from PHP.

Comment: I listed more than one check to perform for a reason :)